# How do I check if a user is logged in after the browser is closed?

Tags: python, html, authentication, flask

I want to check if a user is active and the browser window/tab is still open.
If not I want to set the varibale "loggedIn" in my database to False.

Is that possible?

Thank you in advance :)

Database:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id              =   db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user            =   db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    userDetailed    =   db.Column(db.String(64))
    password        =   db.Column(db.String(64))
    loggedIn        =   db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

Login:

```
@auth.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():

    destination = redirect(url_for("views.editor"))

    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form.get("user")
        password = request.form.get("password")


        user = User.query.filter_by(user=user).first()
        
        
        if user:
            
            if check_password_hash(user.password, password):               
                if user.loggedIn:
                    flash("Error", category="error")
            
                else:
                    user.loggedIn = True
                    login_user(user)
                    db.session.commit()
                    return destination

    return render_template("login.html")
```

Logout:

```
@auth.route("/logout")
@login_required
def logout():
    user = current_user
    user.loggedIn = False
    db.session.commit()
    logout_user()  
    session.clear()
    return redirect(url_for("auth.login"))
```

Comment: If you want a live view, use a websocket and use its disconnect event as indication. Otherwise the best you can do is a “last seen at” which you update with every request.

Answer (score -1):

You can call an API when a browser/window closes the `beforeunload` event is fired.